# Projects should show up only if the user is a team member in openERP

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

We are implementing openERP for internal functioning of our software company and we have this requirement where a person should see a project only if he/she is a team-member of that project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the Record Rule named `Project: employees: public, portal, employees or following`

[image: Find this Record Rule]

Remove `('privacy_visibility', 'in', ['public', 'portal', 'employees']),
                                            '&',` from the rule definition. After this, only people associated as a team-member with a project will be able to view a project.